# Python switch statement with aliases

Tags: python, data-structures, conditional-statements

How to write an efficient "switch" statement that can return same thing for different input?
Simple switch in Python can be implemented using dictionary  like this:

```
def switch(s):
    case = {'phone': '123 456 789', 'website': 'www.example.com'}
    return case[s]
```

This one has constant access time, however I want to use aliases, i.e. `switch('website')` will return the same thing as `switch('site')` etc. without duplicating values, i.e. without using
`case = {'website': 'www.example.com, 'site': 'www.example.com}`
What can be used, is:

```
def switch(s):
    case = {('telephone', 'number', 'phone'): '123 456 789',
            ('website', 'site'): 'www.example.com'}
    for key, value in case.items():
        if s in key:
            return value
```

But this approach has worse than linear access time.
It can be made constant, by using

```
def switch(s):
    case = ['123 456 789', 'www.example.com']
    aliases = {'telephone': 0, 'number': 0, 'phone': 0,
               'website': 1, 'site': 1}
    return case[aliases[s]]
```

but then I'm sort-of duplicating values and in case I decide to remove any answer, I have to edit `aliases`' and/or `case`'s return values (if I no longer want to return `'123 456 789'` I have to delete it from `case` and modify `aliases` so that `aliases['website']` and `aliases['site']` return `0` OR leave dummy value in `case`'s 1st cell OR make `case` a dictionary)

Is there a better way to write such statements?

Comment: I don't think the second example has a non-linear time. With that said, how big is your switches pool?

Comment: In second example you linearly go through all keys and in within each key you check if string is inside this key which also isn't efficient.

Comment: how so? lets take 2 worst and best cases: every tuple key is of length 1. then you get O(n); there is  a single tuple key. O(log(n)).

Comment: To get `switch('site')` (assuming that dictionary is ordered in way I wrote it above), you have to compare `'site'` to all 5 values before finding a match

Comment: which is `O(1)+O(1)=O(1)`

Comment: If there are `n` tuples each of length `m` and key I'm looking for is in last tuple in last cell, It'll find a match after making `n*m` comparisions

Comment: Depending on how you construct it, the dictionary with duplicated values might not require much extra storage space. That's because the duplicated strings can just be multiple references to the same string. Often Python will do that for you automatically (e.g. repeated string literals within the same module will usually all become references to a single object). If you build the dictionary with code rather than literals, you could probably ensure that it always happens.

Comment: In my opinion, you should put into the program an easy to read (and maintain) data structure like the example #2 and convert it automatically to the O(1) data structure from the answer already given.

Comment: @VPfB none of the answers uses structure from my 2nd example, both uses 3rd one. I'll probably settle on something similar to MSeifert answer if there will be no better answers. 2nd is easier to read and maintain, but 3rd is faster, easier to save to file(s) and read from them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the linked hashmaps approach:

```
def switch(s):
    alias = {'telephone': 1, 'number': 1, 'phone': 1,
             'website': 2, 'site': 2}
    case = {1: '123 456 789', 2: 'www.example.com'}
    return case[alias[s]]
```

That way you are keeping the `O(1)` lookup time.

Of course, for real data, you'll want to automate the construction of `alias` and `case` maps, but that should be rather straightforward.

Updates/deletes should also be rather simple, since they come down to simple `dict` update/delete.

Also, to make insertion of new values easier, you can use `UUID4` (or some other random value) instead of numbers.

Comment: That's exactly what I used in my 3rd example.

Comment: No, you used a `list` for `alias`. With a `dict` you don't have any problems updating (deleting) values.

Comment: Right below 3rd example I wrote that as 1 of possible fixes to modify it. "OR make `case` a dictionary"

Comment: I missed that sentence, sorry. Anyway, I think the double `dict` lookup is the way to go (because of the reasons I said: constant lookup, insert, update and delete; and small overhead).

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use an `aliases` dictionary without identity aliases besides your original `case` dictionary and check for potential aliases using `get`:

```
def switch(s):
    case = {'phone': '123 456 789', 'website': 'www.example.com'}
    aliases = {'telephone': 'phone', 'number': 'phone', 'site': 'website'}
    return case[aliases.get(s, s)]  # check if it's an alias or use the input as-is
```

That way you don't need to duplicate the values (not in `case` and not in `alias`).

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say:

> I want to use aliases, i.e. `switch('website')` will return the same thing as `switch('site')` etc. without duplicating values

I think your concern about duplicated values is misplaced and you shouldn't reject that approach. Adding an extra dictionary entry with the same string value should not be a problem, and it's the natural way to solve your issue. Don't complicate your code with an extra indirection layer if you don't need to.

I'm assuming your concern with that approach is that it could increase your memory usage, since identical values are stored several times in the dictionary. But most of the time, you won't have multiple separate identical strings, rather, you'll have multiple references to the same string object. Since strings are immutable, Python may substitute in references to preexisting objects when it would appear it should be creating another independent string with the same contents.

You can test this for yourself. Try creating a dictionary with several identical string literals as values, then test the `id` of each one:

```
d = {"a": "foo", "b": "foo", "c": "foo"}

for val in d.values():
    print(id(val))
```

On my system this tells me the `id`s are all the same. I think that multiple identical string literals that are compiled at the same time will always be turned into multiple references to a single string object. In some situations, thanks to string "interning", all strings with certain contents (generally things that look like they could be identifiers) will be shared everywhere in the program. But you probably don't need to care too much about the details. The important thing to realize is that the duplicated strings probably won't use an excessive amount of memory most of the time.

I can't think of any other reason to object to adding all the aliases to a single dictionary. That's the natural solution, so I'd just do it. If memory usage turns out to be an issue later, you might revisit the dictionary to double check that it's being populated with repeated references, not duplicate objects, but I doubt it will matter on the scale of any serious program.

Having code that is easy to use and understand is much more important.

As you've commented that your main concern is not repeating yourself, you might want to set up the dictionary using code to transform another slightly less redundant data structure, rather than doing it directly as a literal.

For instance, the following code uses a dictionary comprehension to turn a list that pairs up sublists of aliases with their values into an easily searchable dictionary:

```
_data = [     # contains (alias_list, value) 2-tuples
    (['telephone', 'number', 'phone'], '123 456 789'),
    (['website', 'site'], 'www.example.com'),
]

case = {alias: value for aliases, value in _data for alias in aliases}
```

You probably want to put this code somewhere where it will only run once (e.g. at the top level, or in a class or instance variable somewhere), rather than having the dictionary comprehension run every time your `switch` function is called. Because the dictionary is mutable, Python won't assume it can use the same dict object for each call (even though it always has the same value).

Comment: My concern is not memory usage at runtime because, as you said, Python will most likely optimize it. My concern is "What happens if I need to change 1 value?". Then I have to change value for every key, but because it will be saved in file, it's easy to miss few keys for which I was supposed to change the value.

Comment: it would be pretty easy to write a few lines of code that produce the dictionary from a sequence that contains the lists of aliases and their values (e.g. the sort of data in your second example). I'll add that to my answer.